# What is the most simple way to make a URL request and get the JSON response?

Tags: java, android, json, http, url

I would like to make a URL request to a language-translation web-service. The response this service gives is in JSON. What tools are the most straightforward ? I do not need to configure HTTP headers, etc. Also is there some integrated JSON parser or should I use an external Java library like http://www.json.org/java/ ?

Comment: Anything is simple as long as you are comfortable at and we are not sure about what you are comfortable at.

Comment: you should be able to find heaps of information here

Comment: Get the [OkHttp library](http://square.github.io/okhttp/) and you're safe to use [`new JSONObject(String)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html) which is in the framework.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) as a JSON parser/cenverter and [Retrofit](https://github.com/square/retrofit) or [OKHttp](https://github.com/square/okhttp) as HTTP client.

Answer (score 0):

The best and the most trusted external jar for **HTTP requests** used in android is **volley**.
**It's Advantages

1)Provides caching by default

2)completely customisable

3)easy to use**
here's the link to the official android documentation that explains volley 
http://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html
here's a good tutorial to get the wheel spinning and to get the jar
http://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/
**For JSON Parsing**
you can go with popular **google gson jar**. There is always an option of the jackson jar as an alternative
Here's a link that should get you started
https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

Answer (score 0):

`FastJson` , made by alibaba's , which is widely used in China and  `DefaultHttpClient` by original framework.